# Pandas: new DataFrame from another DataFrame with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
A   |   B   |   C   |   D
1   |   2   |   4   |   5
0   |   2   |   5   |   2
1   |   1   |   2   |   1
```

I want a new DataFrame that only takes column `B, C`, but only where `A == 1`. This is what I want:

```
B   |   C
2   |   4
1   |   2
```

Although I can first filter the condition where `A == 1`, then take only column `B, C` from the result, but is the a more "pythonic" way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask and columns names in list:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.A == 1, ['B','C']]
```